# Google BIgQuery thinks billing is disabled, will not let me create a dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

It comes up with the error message, "Billing is not enabled for this project." I am on the 60 day trial, my credit card is valid (I have two on my account), and I can successfully create VM's and run Dataflow projects as well, so I can't figure out why BigQuery seems to think billing is not on. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: not a programming question. you should contact google support

Comment: did you activated the BigQuery API support, it may report this when that is not turned on.

Comment: We're having the same issue. I opened a ticket `#07564170` with Google Support.

Comment: This is a know issue Google engineers are actively investigating it. I'll post on this thread once I have an update.

Comment: My apologies for this! https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/bigquery/18011

Comment: The problem should be resolved for most customers, with the remainder coming soon. For outages or bugs (as opposed to usage or programming questions), consider filing an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this out:

There was an issue where the way that BigQuery checks for project billing status was out of sync with how the billing status was being written. This lasted for about 36 hours and affected projects that made state changes during that time. They would have been locked out from creating datasets, loading data, or running queries that specify a destination table.

Service was completely restored to those projects as of 2 PM on 11/11.